# How to accept http request without http version and host header in Go or node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, go

The hardware is old, and it only send data like 
GET /?a=1

Seems that server write in golang/node.js will take this as HTTP/1.1 and since it does not have Host header, the server will respond 400 bad request.
And the http 1.0 standard needs GET /?a=1 HTTP/1.0, is there exist an out of box http server that can accept such non standard request?

I've tried with go's net/http package and node.js's http package, both won't work, since they obey the standard.

Is it possible write such a http server in go or node.js?

**update**:

using netcat to inspect the request:
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It works fine when I tested it using Node's HTTP package. https://www.evernote.com/l/AAOgJZU6G55L85nFBeNEs9Hfov7QdX_gPtE You need to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: HTTP/1.0 is over 20 years old (it's from February 1996). You might want to reconsider your client choices when the client is old enough to vote.

Comment: @Quentin can you try without the HTTP/1.0 part? the device I use only send a GET /

Comment: @Art seems that the provider does not obey any standard (the request are not an standard HTTP/1.0 request either), I'll consider your suggestion.

Comment: @cgcgbcbc A raw "GET /foo" is also known as HTTP 0.9, the original http from before it was standardized. In other words what clients were doing between 1992 and 1996.

Comment: @Art Thanks! I was inspired by your comment, and it seems that the old device requires me manually write the data like `foo HTTP/1.1\nHost: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx\n\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP servers are fairly easy to write. I've written at least 2. As a guide I strongly recommend you read ["HTTP Made Really Easy"](https://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/). It was first published in 1997 and I first used it to write my first server in 2002.

Basically, an HTTP server needs to wait for double newlines (`"\n\n"`). If there is a `Content-Length` header then it needs to read that many bytes of input (that is for POST and PUT requests).

That's it. Everything else is about how to interpret the data you've got.

Oh, there's also chunked transfer encoding but that's only mandatory for HTTP/1.1 servers and above. Just identify yourself as an HTTP/0.9 server.

To see how simple a web server can be see: http://wiki.tcl.tk/28414 (8 lines of code)

Here's a similar server in javascript:

```
// WARNING: Does not support POST or PUT body
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(sock){
  var buffer = '';

  sock.on('data', function(chunk){
    buffer += chunk.toString('utf8'); // assumptions!!

    if (buffer.match(/(\r?\n){2}/)) { // looking for double \n\n
      sock.write("HTTP/0.9 200 OK\nConnection:close\n\n");
      sock.write("Hello!");
      sock.end();
    }
  });
});

server.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('Server started');
});
```

You can process the request by processing the `buffer` string. The first line is the `GET` line.